# Алгоритм декстеры, выбор ребер/вершин

Tags: c++

C++ Дана программа в которой выполняется алгоритм поиска кратчайшего расстояния . В данном примере присутствует 5 вершин , нужно реализовать возможность пользователю удалять / выключать вершину ( чтобы кратчайший путь через неё не проходил ) (либо как я понял можно ужалить столбец  , но тоже не понимаю , как сделать это нормально ), либо заменить весь столбец нулями (но это я тоже не понимаю как реализовать ) . Я новичок в программирование и в c++ очень плохо разбираюсь .

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    vector<int> parent(5, -1); // объявили и сразу заполнили -1-цами в кол-ве 5 штук
    double big_num(10000);
    double matrix[5][5] =
    { {0.02,5.01,12.05,0.01,0.4},
      {5.01,0.05,4.01,0.01,1.01},
      {12.01,4.1,0.2,2.2,0.6},
      {0.2,0.01,2.21,0.45,5.21},
      {0.2,1.01,0.21,5.45,0.2} };

    double  pos[5];
    int node[5], min(0), index_min(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        pos[i] = big_num;
        node[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            cout << setw(4) << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    int x;

    cout << "vvedite x1";

    cin >> x;
    pos[x - 1] = 0; // начальная точка 
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        min = big_num;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            if (!node[j] && pos[j] < min) {
                min = pos[j];
                index_min = j;
            }
        }
        node[index_min] = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            if (!node[j] && matrix[index_min][j] > 0 && pos[index_min] != big_num && pos[index_min] + matrix[index_min][j] < pos[j]) {
                pos[j] = pos[index_min] + matrix[index_min][j];
                parent.at(j) = index_min; // запоминаем предка вершины j
            }
        }
    }
    int n(0);
    cout << "\nnumber of top? : ";
    cin >> n;

    vector<int>temp; // n - 1, так как не забываем про индексацию
    for (int i = n - 1; i != -1; i = parent.at(i))temp.push_back(i + 1); // а все что здесь делается описано в справке,которую я те кинул
    reverse(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); ++i)cout << temp.at(i) << " ";

    cout << "\nWeight : " << pos[n - 1] << "\n";

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
    cout << "готово";
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Алгоритм Дейкстры нахождения кратчайшего пути, выбор вершин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1210529/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd)

Comment: Бедный Дейкстра... декстер... :(